# Best practices for creating cross platform application using xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a business application for Android and iOS, using Xamarin.
Applications for both operating systems (Android and iOS) will have the same layout.
Functionality is simple - User login, Table views, Map views, Search & filter, Navigation menu, video play lists etc.

I'll pick one of these approaches when creating the app:

- Create separate versions of the app with Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Ios
- Make the app cross-platform with Xamarin.Forms

What are the pros and cons that I should be aware of with both approaches?

Comment: This can't be meaningfully answered on SO.  It depends on your specific requirements and preferences - there is no "right" answer.  I suggest visiting the Xamarin forums if you want to get some opinions about the pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Forms is best for:
Apps that require little platform-specific functionality
Apps where code sharing is more important than custom UI
Developers comfortable with XAML

Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android are best for:
Apps with interactions that require native behavior
Apps that use many platform-specific APIs
Apps where custom UI is more important than code sharing

If i was in your place, would've chosen Xamarin.Forms